# Add calendar event after certain event?

Tags: calendar, ical

If I have a few 'Today is C' scattered around my calendar randomly, is there any way I can add an iCal event after on all the days that contain an event title 'Today is C'?

Quite confusing, but this is what I have in a nut shell

```
| 9/2/12 Today is C|
| 9/6/12 Today is C|
| 9/7/12 Today is C|
|12/5/12 Today is C|
```

But I want this to happen automatically:

```
| 9/2/12 Today is C|
| 9/2/12 GOOD|
| 9/6/12 Today is C|
| 9/6/12 GOOD|
| 9/7/12 Today is C|
| 12/7/12 GOOD|
|12/5/12 Today is C|
```

Comment: Did you try anything your self? Like Automator ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes. I could get it to work if Automator would supply the event date to the Create new Event object